# Call Kotlin code from java -> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture;

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

Android Studio 3.4.2

I has **java** file (**which I'm not able to convert to Kotlin for now**).

in build.gradle:

```
     android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        compileSdkVersion 29
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1296
            versionName "2.3.1296"
            testInstrumentationRunner 

"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    def RETROFIT_VERSION = '2.6.0'
    def KOTLIN_COROUTINE_VERSION = '1.2.1'
    ext.KOTLIN_VERSION = '1.3.41'

dependencies {   
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$KOTLIN_VERSION"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$KOTLIN_COROUTINE_VERSION"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$KOTLIN_COROUTINE_VERSION"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.2.2'
```

In my activity - **java** file (**which I'm not able to convert to Kotlin for now**):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import com.myproject.services.transport.TransportService;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

CompletableFuture<Response<?>> response = TransportService.doLogin("email", "pass", false);

}
```

Here is Kotlin file snippet:

```
import android.util.Log
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.future.future
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import retrofit2.Response
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

class TransportService {
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun doLogin(
            email: String,
            password: String,
            isCustomtHandle: Boolean = false
        ): CompletableFuture<Response<*>> = GlobalScope.future { // error here
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "doLogin_login = $isCustomtHandle")
            login(email, password, isCustomtHandle)
        }


suspend fun login(email: String, password: String, isCustomtHandle: Boolean = false): Response<*> {... }
```

But I get runtime error in this line:

```
 CompletableFuture<Response<*>> = GlobalScope.future {
```

Here error message in Kotlin file:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22132): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-2
E/AndroidRuntime(22132): Process: com.myptoject.debug, PID: 22132
E/AndroidRuntime(22132): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture;
E/AndroidRuntime(22132):    at kotlinx.coroutines.future.FutureKt.future(Future.kt:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(22132):    at kotlinx.coroutines.future.FutureKt.future$default(Future.kt:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(22132):    at com.myproject.services.transport.TransportService$Companion.doLogin(TransportService.kt:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(22132):    at com.myproject.services.transport.TransportService.doLogin(TransportService.kt)
E/AndroidRuntime(22132):    at com.myptoject.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime(22132):    at com.myptoject.LoginActivity_.access$001(LoginActivity_.java:22)
```

What is wrong with my code?

P.S.

```
 minSdkVersion 23
```

This is this is customer requirement. So I can't increment it

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [`CompletableFuture` reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture), it is only available after API level 24, so if your requirements require sdk 23 you cannot use that class.

However there are two roughly equivalent classes available to you:

- Guava\androidx.concurrent's `ListenableFuture`: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent + https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/
- kotlinx.coroutines's `Deferred`/`CompletableDeferred`: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-deferred/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture` is only available in Java 8 an newer.

I would try using "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-**jdk8**:$KOTLIN_VERSION" instead of the jdk7 implementation in the build.gradle file.

You could also try adding `kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }` inside the `compileOptions` block.

Comment: Work on Android 9.0, but not work on Android 6.0. I get same error.